# What does [文] as in "[文]のに対して" stand for?

Tags: grammar

I stumbled on this grammar formula in the 日本語総まとめＮ３ book: "[文]のに対して", but I'm not sure what [文] stands for. Does it mean a sentence? If it is a sentence, it should end in either N/A/Na/V in 普通形 form, so according to the formula, this should be legit:

> 田中先生は生徒だのに対して厳しい。

but is it really grammatically correct? The book also writes "Nに対して" and its example is:

> 田中先生は生徒に対して厳しい.

This [文] part really confuses me, and the book doesn't explain what it stands for, even though it appears a lot in the book. Please help me!

Answer (score 5):

～のに対して basically means *whereas* which connects two "sentences". Here are some examples:

- 田中先生は優しいのに対して、木村先生は厳しい。
- 田中先生は高齢であるのに対して、木村先生は若い。
- 田中先生は英語ができるのに対して、木村先生はできない。

So the phrases before のに look like legitimate 文, don't they?

「田中先生は生徒だのに対して厳しい」 makes little sense because it doesn't connect two sentences. (Actually this sentence may make sense because [だの happens to mean "things like ～"](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/138101/meaning/m0u/%E3%81%A0%E3%81%AE/), but let's forget about this for now)

This の in のに対して is actually a nominalizer, and [the general grammatical rule for the nominalizers](http://people.uncw.edu/kanoy/practices/NominalizersKotoNo.htm) is applied. That means you cannot put everything that looks like a sentence. For example, 「田中先生は高齢だのに対して、木村先生は若い。」 is ungrammatical.

---

**EDIT**: As you can see in this N3 sample question, `[文]` does not always look like a legit 文 (短気な is the dictionary form of a na-adjective, but you have to say 父は短気だ in a real 文, of course). So you should understand this `[文]` as "a nominalize-able phrase which sometimes (but not always) looks like a sentence."

[image]

Comment: Thanks naruto-san and @choco san! I think I understand what the book means by the formula:  "Nに対して"&"[文]のに対して" now. It means their should be a noun or a nominalized phrase preceding に対して, thus there are such cases: 
>verb(普通形) + の + に対して
>i adj (普通形) + の +に対して
>na adj (stem) + な + の + に対して
>Noun (stem) + に対して.
By 普通形, I mean their dictionary form, negative form, and past form. By stem, I mean it isn't succeeded by anything. 
Am I correct?

Answer (score 2):

[sentence] のに対して has two meanings: One is "whereas" as naruto-san explained.

The other is "for". For example, 先生は生徒が喫煙するのに対して厳しい. This の means こと and it nominalizes a sentence 生徒が喫煙する. 先生は生徒が喫煙するのに対して厳しい means the same as 先生は生徒の喫煙に対して厳しい.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @naruto san and @choco san! I think I understand what the book means by the formula: "Nに対して"&"[文]のに対して" now. It means their should be a noun or a nominalized phrase preceding に対して, thus there are such cases:

> verb(普通形) + の + に対して 
>   i adj (普通形) + の +に対して 
>   na adj (stem) + な + の + に対して
>  
>   Noun (stem) + に対して

By 普通形, I mean their dictionary form, negative form, and past form. By stem, I mean it isn't succeeded by anything. 
Am I correct?